# SQL Alchemy ORM Query Does not Include Inner Join Condition

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, orm, pyathena

The problem is as the question says. Using AWS athena server with pyathena engine.

Here is some context. I am basically filtering on a table containing all the bookings, to include only most recent ones based on an `earliest_history` date (anything earlier than that will be dropped).
I need two columns after this, the date and the customer id.

There is another table mapping customer id to some other data, that I need to join with the previous result. Here is how I am implementing it in sql alchemy ORM.

```py
# SELECT date, customer_id FROM bookings 
query: Query = session.query(func.date(bookings.columns[TIMESTAMP]).label(name=TIMESTAMP), 
                             bookings.columns[CUSTOMER_ID])
# Alias as I need to get some filter
all_history: Alias = cast(typ=Alias, val=aliased(element=query.subquery()))
# noinspection PyTypeChecker
# SELECT * FROM all_history WHERE timestamp>=earliest_history
query = session.query(all_history).filter(
    all_history.columns[TIMESTAMP] >= func.date(earliest_history)).distinct()
# noinspection PyTypeChecker
customer_results: Alias = aliased(element=query.subquery())
mapping_table: str = config.get(section='db', option='MAPPING_TABLE', raw=True)
mappings: Table = metadata.tables[mapping_table]
# noinspection PyTypeChecker
# Inner join customer results with the mappings table
join = customer_results.join(right=mappings,
                             onclause=mappings.columns[CUSTOMER_ID_MAPPING] == customer_results.columns[CUSTOMER_ID])
query=session.query(join)
raw_query: str = str(query.statement.compile(compile_kwargs={'literal_binds': True}))
print(raw_query)
```

The problem is, this is the raw_query (formatting and comments mine)

```sql
SELECT 
  anon_1.booking_dt, 
  anon_1.cust_id, 
  customer_mapping.ustb_customer_id, 
  customer_mapping.ustb_customer_create_time, 
  customer_mapping.esc_customer_id, 
  customer_mapping.esc_customer_create_time 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      DISTINCT anon_2.booking_dt AS booking_dt, 
      anon_2.cust_id AS cust_id 
    FROM 
      (
        SELECT 
          date(esc_booking.booking_dt) AS booking_dt, 
          esc_booking.cust_id AS cust_id 
        FROM 
          esc_booking
      ) AS anon_2 
    WHERE 
      anon_2.booking_dt >= date('2023-11-29')
  ) AS anon_1, -- Should I expect the join clause here? 
  customer_mapping; -- What does it mean?
```

Basically, it seems alchemy is totally removing my join clause for some reason. How to get sql alchemy to really perform the join?

Related, is the `filter` method in SQL Alchemy an ORM counterpart of `SELECT * WHERE` or of `JOIN`?

Comment: It would be helpful to have minimal model and table definitions so that we don;t have to reverse engineer them from the code.

Comment: `filter` corresponds to a `where` clause.  https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.filter